# Low quality postdoc application and deadline extension

Tags: application, postdocs, deadlines

I was interested in a postdoc offer and forgot about the deadline.

I remembered the deadline to apply was today. I rushed to make a CV and motivation letter and sent it at 23h59. The day after, the PI sent a message on a job offer mailing list saying that the deadline is extended for one week.

The question is: should I rewrite a better application and send it again, or just wait for an answer on my poorly written application? Or, maybe there is another solution? (And yes, the best solution is to prepare an application before the deadline)

If anybody has any ideas as to what to make of this situation, please do share. In advance, Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you contacted the PI directly already?

Comment: Nope, I directly sent a mail to a person that seemed to be HR.

Comment: You can always add material and submit again, regardless of deadlines. Sometimes people get publications and awards after they submitted their materials. You shouldn't totally change major things like career goals or plans, or you may look indecisive or insincere.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Contact them, explain yourself, and ask if it is OK to resubmit your application. (And make sure that you can submit a significantly better application before the new deadline.)

This has the added advantage of bringing you in contact with the PI, and putting yourself on their radar.